# Using external variables in psycopg2 / postgres command

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have thousands of related CSVs and I want to write their contents to a Postgres table in a way that includes metadata about where each row came from.

I am not clear on how to write the variables I created near the top of my script into the table.

Can anyone advise?

```
target_directory = Path(sys.argv[1]).resolve()

# FOR THE WAC AND RAC DATASETS
for file in target_directory.rglob('*.csv'):
    print(str(file.stem).split('_'))

    state = str(file.stem).split('_')[0]
    data_category = str(file.stem).split('_')[1]
    workforce_segment = str(file.stem).split('_')[2] # THIS IS DIFFERENT FROM THE O-D DATASETS
    job_type = str(file.stem).split('_')[3]
    year = str(file.stem).split('_')[4]


    print('Writing: ' + str(file.name))

    # MAKE SURE THIS IS THE RIGHT TABLE FOR THE FILES
    cur.execute(create_table_WAC)

    with open(file,'r') as file_in:

        # INSERT THE DATA IN USING THE COLUMN NAMES....SO YOU CAN ADD YOUR SPLIT STRING INFO ABOVE.....
        # MAKE SURE THIS HAS THE RIGHT TABLE NAME IN THE COPY STATEMENT
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO opendata_uscensus_usa_lodes_wac (serial_id, state_name, data_category, workforce_segment, job_type, year, w_geocode, C000, CA01, CA02, CA03, CE01, CE02) \
        VALUES (%s, state_name, data_category, workforce_segment, job_type, year, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")

        conn.commit()

conn.close()
```

Comment: How are you creating a table with each iteration of loop but inserting into one table per loop? This would leave many empty tables.

Comment: @Parfait - Excellent point...did not catch that previously...

Answer (score 1):

As per [PEP-249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15) (Python Database API Specification) which most DB-APIs adhere to including  `pymssql`, `cx_oracle`, `ibm_db`, `pymysql`, `sqlite3`, and `pyodbc`, in `psycopg2` variables to be binded as parameters in prepared statements  would go into the second argument of [`cur.execute(query, params)`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15).

Specifically, combine your file level variables with CSV variables during iteration and pass them as a list or tuple of parameters into execution call. Below uses the [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) method that builds a dictionary of every row from csv data.

**NOTE:** below query leaves out primary key, *serial_id*, which should populate via a sequence in Postgres table.

```
for file in target_directory.rglob('*.csv'):
    print(str(file.stem).split('_'))

    # FILE LEVEL VARIABLES
    state_name = str(file.stem).split('_')[0]
    data_category = str(file.stem).split('_')[1]
    workforce_segment = str(file.stem).split('_')[2]
    job_type = str(file.stem).split('_')[3]
    year = str(file.stem).split('_')[4]

    # PREPARED STATEMENT
    sql = """INSERT INTO opendata_uscensus_usa_lodes_wac  
                  (state_name, data_category, workforce_segment,
                   job_type, year, w_geocode, C000, CA01, CA02, CA03, CE01, CE02)
             VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""

    with open(file,'r') as file_in:
        # ITERATE THROUGH FOR CSV VARIABLES
        reader = csv.DictReader(file_in)
        for row in reader:
           cur.execute(sql, (state,data_category,workforce_segment,job_type,year,
                             row['w_geocode'], row['C000'], row['CA01'],
                             row['CA02'], row['CA03'], row['CE01'], row['CE02'])
                       )

        conn.commit()
```

Comment: I mostly understand this -- I can see how it inputs the values from python -- but I'm lost on how the data coming from the table (and the primary key column) would end up in the table.

Comment: I don't understand your issue: *data coming from the table would end up in the table*. Can you rephrase? I hope you are not confusing your variables which are the same name as your columns. Python variables used in parameters can be named anything.

Comment: Some of the values (metadata about the file) are coming from the python script and some of the values are coming from the CSV.  I don't understand how the CSV values would end up in the table.

Comment: Please show CSV. You need to iterate through its rows. There are many such examples on SO.

Comment: I added example rows segment to the original post. The `state_name, data_category, workforce_segment, job_type, year` variables are pulled from the file name rather than inside the CSV.

Comment: See edited code combining your *file* level and *CSV* data into the params for query.